# Bertrand Russell about Aristotle

Tags: metaphysics, history-of-philosophy, aristotle, bertrand-russell

Why does Bertrand Russell say that Aristotle was the last Greek philosopher to face the world cheerfully?

...
I need(!) an answer to this question. I've read the whole chapter on Aristotle (in the History of Western Philosophy) and googled this quote, but I didn't find what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bertand Russell](https://books.google.it/books?id=iQZ6Xk9VdtAC&pg=PA232) is discussing [Hellenistic philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenistic_philosophy) : [Stoic philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoicism), [skepticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhonism),  [Cynic philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynicism_(philosophy)) etc.

He defines it a "philosophy of retreat", without interest in the world (considered bad) and thus not interested to promote science nor progress.

Compare with [Aristotle's desire to understand](https://books.google.it/books?id=hSAGlzPLq7gC&pg=PA1).